# What http headers are used to specify "open in new tab" and "download location dialog"

Tags: php, http-headers

I've been using links with target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" for quite some time.  However, now I have created a file that I wish to "download" to the client and have it opened in a new tab.  I have not been able to find a set of http headers that will do this. I'm sure they have to exist, since the links can specify "_blank" but I'll be darned if I can find header info.

```
header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
if (headers_sent()) {
    $this->Error('Some data has already been output to browser, can\'t send PDF file');
}
header('Cache-Control: private, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0, max-age=1');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT'); // Date in the past
header('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s').' GMT');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . rawurlencode(basename($name)) . '"; ' . 'filename*=UTF-8\'\'' . rawurlencode(basename($name)));
```

Also, although I have Firefox set to "always ask where to save downloads" it does not... it just saves them to the default location. No dialog box opens.  Can that be set using an http header?

```
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
if (headers_sent()) {
    $this->Error('Some data has already been output to browser, can\'t send PDF file');
}
header('Cache-Control: private, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0, max-age=1');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT'); // Date in the past
header('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s').' GMT');
// force download dialog
if (strpos(php_sapi_name(), 'cgi') === false) {
    header('Content-Type: application/force-download');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream', false);
    header('Content-Type: application/download', false);
    header('Content-Type: application/pdf', false);
} else {
    header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
}
// use the Content-Disposition header to supply a recommended filename
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . rawurlencode(basename($name)) . '";' . 'filename*=UTF-8\'\'' . rawurlencode(basename($name)));
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
```

Thanks in advance for any assistance,

Comment: Why send multiple `Content-Type` headers? Why send `Content-Transfer-Encoding`?

Comment: The server has no control over what the client does with the received data. It can make suggestions via the headers but it can't force anything. Bear in mind the server doesn't even know if the receiving client is a browser - so expecting it to be able to control whether the browser opens something in a new tab isn't reasonable. Likewise for "downloading"...and that could arguablly be a security issue too.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I was trying to get too much control over user!  By the way, the reason for all the Content-Type headers was I was trying to force my browser to open a Download Dialog Box before saving the file to the "last used folder."  I still have not figured that one out!

Comment: But each content-type header will just contradict the other, the browser can't take note of all of them.